# Junit expected exception fails

Tags: java, junit

I'm trying to test a load method, which throws a StreamCorruptedException. But when i'm testing it with junit 4, the test fails.

My load method:

```
 public BookDataProvider(String filename) throws StreamCorruptedException { ... }
```

My test class:

```
public class TestClass {
   @Test (expected=StreamCorruptedException.class)
   public void wrongFileTest() throws StreamCorruptedException  {
       BookDataProvider bdp = new BookDataProvider("wrong filename");
   }
}
```

The method throws the exception, but the test fails. What did i do wrong?

Comment: it looks right are you sure about the exception? maybe it is different ?

Comment: Yes, I've had this before as well... add the package in front of the class to be sure.  Also, try catching Exception.class and then move on to your own.  Do you see the exception if you remove the annotation?

Comment: Try removing the annotation and catching the exception just to see if you are getting what you thing your are.  If so, then we can dig a little deeper.  Could you be catching the StreamCorruptedException before it reaches the test case and re throwing something else?

Comment: I found out that i have to add catch (IOException i) {}  and catch (ClassNotFoundException c) {} after file reading. StreamCorruptedException is extends IOException, so it catched in the load method, and not thrown. I tried to add catch(StreamCorruptedException s) before IOException, but it didn't worked.

Comment: Please provide the Stacktrace of **new BookDataProvider("wrong filename")** It may an ExceptionInInitializerError http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError.html

Comment: Did you find out why this happened? I've been looking the only reason I could find would be jUnit 3, but I'm on 4.8.x

Answer (score 1):

From your code, I see that your test is passing a wrong file name to `BookDataProvider` constructor and this does not cause StreamCorruptedException, it will only cause IOException. StreamCorruptedException occurs due to failure of deserialisation of data mostly due to difference in stream used for writing and reading. For example, it happens when trying to read data using ObjectInputStream if it was not written using ObjectOutputStream.

Comment: The file with "wrong file name exists, but it's an image, so it should throw StreamCorruptedException.